# Google sheets formula to capture specific data

Tags: google-sheets

Google sheets formula to capture specific data from a spreadsheet each month where the data changes each month:

Essentially, I want to capture the metrics on the last day of each month (to another sheet) while the data in the spreadsheet I'm pulling from will change every month.

My goal:

```
Capture metrics on 11/30
-->the metrics will then change in December
Capture all metric on 12/31
-->the metrics will then change in January.
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done by use a formula but it could be done by using Google Apps Script, more specifically by using an Apps Script function called by a time-driven trigger.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Thanks. The trigger function worked after creating a macro. Given the data points will change month to month - my macro also included to copy and paste the data as values only.